# Single, unzipped PHP file as plugin?

Tags: plugins

WordPress plugins commonly come in the form of a "zip" file, which can contain multiple files of PHP source code. Can a plugin come in the form of a single, unzipped, PHP source code file, with a ".php" extension?

I tried to upload a single, ".php" file as a plugin to an ancient WP 2.9.2 test blog I have lying around (not connected to the Internet), and that failed. It looks like WP 2.9.2 only accepts .zip files. If modern WP installations accept unzipped ".php" files, when did that change take place?

Comment: Had you tried it?.. From quick test modern install doesn't allow to upload non-zip file for a plugin through admin interface either.